# Error: Visual Studio IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

Solicito de su ayuda ya que al ejecutar mi programa, me arroja este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente cambiarle la dirección del Localhost, reiniciar y apagar mi máquina pero el error aún aparece. Incluso elimine la carpeta .vs

Les agradeceria mucho, la versión de mi VS es 2017

Comment: Es necesario revisar los logs y el VIsor de eventos. ¿Qué sale?

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado Visual Studio 2017 como administrador? Por cierto, bienvenida a SOes, te recomiendo que vayas a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y del mismo modo obtengas tu primera medalla, revisa también cómo preguntar en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y como dife @Alfabravo mira en el visor de eventos del Windows

Comment: Para revisar los logs, esto podría darte una idea: http://fredyfx.com/post/solucionando-http-error-503-en-el-iis/

Comment: si creas un nuevo proyecto web en VS2017, puedes iniciarlo? o estas obteniendo el mismo mensaje. Solo para descartar si es problema de ese proyecto o es general

Comment: Cambiar la dirección de localhost?  Por qué?  Es como cambiar a quien refiere "mi."

Comment: Suena tonta mi pregunta pero primero has ejecutado iis express directamente desde el menu?  despues de eso procederemos a la configuracion de ejecucion.